# Getting ending part in nesting dot notation name react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hook-form

I'm trying to get the last part of a dot notation name in react-hook-form. I have:

`const one = array.0.propertyName`

`const two = anotherPropertyName`

And I want just to get `propertyName` and `anotherPropertyName`, is there a way to get those parts without doing something like:

```
let property;
if(one.includes('.')) {
   property = one.split('.').pop();
}
```

I mean a method that already exists in react-hook-form.

Thank you!